# Collapseable Text Menu

Tags: css, html

I'm making a website for my web dev class, and I had an idea to make the nav with single letters representing the menu items, but when you hover over the letter, they expand into full word(s).

Example:
If a menu item is shown as "[A]", when you hover over the letter, it expands into "[About]".

Is this something that can be done in HTML5/CSS, or do I need JavaScript, jQuery, etc?

Comment: I think you need JS with hover event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this effect with CSS. This code probably can be even optimized a lot but it's just to give you a rough idea of how your desired effect could look like.

**HTML**

```
<nav>
  <a href="">About</a>
  <a href="">Test</a>
  <a href="">About</a>
  <a href="">Test</a>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  height: 80px;
  align-items: center;
  background: #eee;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

a {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  font-size: 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:first-letter {
  font-size: initial;
}

a:hover {
  font-size: initial;
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
nav {
  height: 80px;
  align-items: center;
  background: #eee;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
a {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  font-size: 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:first-letter {
  font-size: initial;
}
a:hover {
  font-size: initial;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="">About</a>
  <a href="">Test</a>
  <a href="">About</a>
  <a href="">Test</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: This is probably the closest possible answer to what I'm looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose You can use :after or :before pseudoelement attribute named "content" :

```css
a:hover:after {      
  content: "after hovering";
 }
```

```html
<a> A </a>
```

You can do this also with javascript, all depends how does it fits your current workflow.

Comment: Is there a way to hide the previuos text, i.e. "A"?
Currently it will display as "Aafter hovering". when the user is hovering over it.

Comment: No, there isn't. The content property is referring only to :before and :after pseudoclass. --> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content

You will need to apply javascript to do this .